# How to extend up-time after power supply is gone

Tags: batteries, capacitor, motor, dc-dc-converter, generator

I just started to work on a small home project. I have an indoor bike that I use quite a lot. The resistance of the bike can be adjusted manually in a purely mechanical way (by tightening a screw). And I have some 24V DC motors laying around, so I thought, why not combine the two and create a smarter bike.

My plan is to connect the motor to the bike and use a MOSFET and PWM to set the resistance level. When I exercise, the *generator* is going to generate some DC voltage, depending on the speed. I feed it through a bridge rectifier, just in case, then I place an N-channel MOSFET for setting the resistance level using a PWM signal.

This is very simple so far, but now comes the fun part. I also want to run the circuit that handles the automatic difficulty setting using the power generated from the motor. But since the resistance is set using a PWM signal, the output voltage is also a square wave. Therefore, I add some capacitance after a diode to smooth out the voltage. I also added a zener diode to prevent too high voltages, just in case. I convert the output DC voltage of the motor to 5V (needed for the encoder of the motor and maybe some other circuitry) using a buck converter, and then I convert the 5V to 3.3V using an LDO. There, I will place my ESP or STM-based microcontroller circuit, which should not draw much current.

I also want to measure both the input voltage and the 5V voltage line, and when it drops to an insufficient level, I want to have enough time to persist some data by writing it to a flash memory or an SD card. I will work on the low voltage detection later with some transistor-based interrupt line.

You can find my current design later. Is this a viable idea? To use capacitors to extend the uptime with a couple of milliseconds for persisting data? Where should I place the capacitances, on which voltage line? I thought about putting them on the 3.3V line, because that is the most crucial circuit that would need to be up the longest. But when the supply voltage is gone and the circuit draws current from the capacitor, then the voltage of the capacitor will start to drop as well. Therefore, maybe I should pack capacitors on the 5V line or even the 24V line, so that even if that voltage drops, I will still have a stable 3.3V for the circuit. But then if I put the capacitances on the 24V or 5V line, then the additional circuitry will drain it faster. Or maybe put extra capacitances everywhere, so that every line has its own storage, and then the 3.3V line is up for the most time. But I don't necessarily want to overload the circuit with capacitances either. What capacitance size would you recommend using?

[image]

Comment: Note:  The D1 bridge must be made of high-speed diodes.  1N4000 series diodes will not work well.  Can you measure the peak frequency of the voltage out of the motor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what supercaps are used for. Use a diode before them so they so they do not get reverse drained in the wrong direction once power is lost.

For a capacitor of the same capacitance, if it can tolerate the voltage on the input side of the LDO it is better to put it there because that provides voltage overhead to compensate for the voltage dropping when you lose power. The LDO then regulates it down and you get a flatter supply voltage for longer.

If you place a capacitor on the output side of the LDO, your supply voltage will immediately begin to drop below nominal when you lose power.

If you want to bypass extraneous circuitry to reduce loading, you can put a dedicated regulator for the components in question.

Make sure to choose an LDO with a PMOS pass element. These will essentially become pass-through when the regulator enters drop out allowing you to squeeze every last bit of charge from the capacitor that is in your operating voltage range. Other types of LDOs may not do this and just cut the voltage off when entering dropout.

Comment: Does one Farad make sense, capacity -wise? The competition has driven the price below $1, and the 1F are cheaper than the 100mF.  Like 71cents... $7.05 for 10, DigiKey-# 535-ADCR-S03R0SA105MB-ND, Abracon-# ADCR-S03R0SA105MB, 1F (EDLC) Supercap 3V 350mOhm.

Comment: 1F is really big and should work, especially if it can tolerate the voltage on the input side of the linear regulator. 1F is so big it would do fine on the output side too.

Comment: If you do decide to series them so they can sit at the 5V input be aware the voltage will be split between them proportionall based on their ACTUAL capacitance. So if they are identical, 2.5V per cap which is still under their 3V rating. But caps have tolerance and past some point the voltage will be split unevenly such that the voltage on one cap might exceed it's rating. 3V is 20% larger than 2.5V so if both caps are within 20% of each other you should be okay without extra measures (which involve balancing resistors which sap power which you do not want to need here).

Comment: Remember, that is within 20% of each other. So if the caps are 10% tolerance but one is on the low end and one is on the high end they could be 20% apart. This includes variation of temperature too. I'm not sure how much that varies for supercaps. You could always leave space on your PCB and choose to populate them or not populate them after the fact.

Comment: Tolerance on example supercap is ±20%, which means they could be 40% apart, so that's a problem. With 3 in series, we get 333mF, 5V/3=1.67V each, 71cents x 3 =$2.13, 3 x 350mOhm = 1.05Ohm.  Probably better to use a supercap made for the voltage? (but ESR is 30!):   $12.09 for 10, DigiKey # 4688-CE5R5105VF-ZJ-ND, CDA (Zhifengwei) # CE5R5105VF-ZJ, 1F -20% +80% (EDLC) Supercap 5.5V, 30-Ohm @ 1kHz.

Answer (score 0):

Super capacitor or large capacitors (reservoir capacitor) are much cheaper, and sometimes exist only for low voltage. It's better to place the reservoir capacitor after the LDO because the linear voltage regulators just waste the energy that is between the input voltage and output voltage (so to speak).

A step down regulator will also waste 15 to 20% of energy. Thought a large capacitor on the 24V side could increase the efficiency a little bit because it will power the LDO until it reaches 4V. So it has 20V to go before it says bye bye.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHLEwK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: And does it not bother the LDO that the output is kind of shorted to ground until the capacitor is charged? And another question, can current flow "backwards" through the LDO, do I need the diode? Or maybe put the diode after the power indicating LED so that it does not draw current unnecessarily?

Comment: No, because the resistance between the LDO output and ground increases as the capacitor charges. With large capacitor, you should use a stronger LDO than just for the current used by the circuit, the time the capacitor resistor increases, but not that strong, because the time when resistance is low is quiet short and the LDO can tolerate some over current for a short time.

Comment: The LDO may not let the current flow backward, though the internal circuitry and the datasheet should be carefully inspected to make sure there is no leakage, It's also safer for the LDO not to let higher voltage on the output than on the input. So it's better, if not necessary, to have the diode. As you said, the diode can be placed strategically so that only critical components are powered during off time. Bypassing, i.e.,the indicator LED is a good idea. An IC on standby can keep data for several minutes or even hours.

Comment: You can also add a resistor in series with the largest capacitor, just in case.

Comment: I disagree with the supercap on the output side if the supercap of the same value can tolerate the voltage on the input side  because your supply voltage is going to immediately start dropping below your nominal when you lose power. If it's on the input you get a flatter output voltage for longer with the super cap on the input because it's above the voltage you need and the regulator regulates it down. The LDO is a red herring due to the way the LDO works. You aren't getting extra run time with it on the output. In fact, you get less (assuming the same capacitance).

Comment: DK beat me by 32 minutes.  Moving the hold-up cap to the regulator input usually means having a cap rated for a higher voltage.  But the total energy stored is proportional to the *square* of the voltage, so the energy equations favor this approach.  Also, while it is good to have the power chain as efficient as possible, remember that by definition the cap is being charged up by excess energy not used elsewhere.  80% of large and free is much better than 10% of small but efficient.  10% is the tolerable voltage drop from the LDO into the uC, from 3.3 v to 3.0 V.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm not sure if I can agree with this totally. Because the  process in linear regulation is losing energy. If your goal is to have a flat and stable 3V for as long as possible, then I will agree. But these ICs can retain data with as low as 1.5V. That's 50% of 3V. 50% of 5V is 2.5V and at 3.15V the LDO doesn't output anything (unless I'm mistaken).  Another advantage is cost and size are much smaller for 3V than for 5V. From 5V to 3V you can also use a non LDO regulator (ie.L78)). Not if you rely on a gradually decreasing 5 to 3.3V supply.

Comment: @AnalogKid ...That's why I suggested adding a large cap on the 24V. This will make it even more efficient than on the 5V side. Then a second diode should be placed before the 24V cap. The best IMO is to have large caps before and after the LDO. So that when the LDO doesn't yield anything, you still have a reserve.